How is high voltage created in X-ray systems and cathode ray tubes?
I am interested building a circuit producing high voltage (20-30kV) without any issues. In all the circuits I've built, such as a ZVS driver, DC-DC boost converters, and Tesla coil, the flow was very unstable and could not run for 5-10 minutes.
How is the high voltage produced efficiently and continuously in X-ray machines and cathode-ray tubes? I would like to build a device that supplies high voltage (20-30kV) continuously with minimal issues from a 12v DC battery. Additionally, for safety reasons, I don't want the circuit to draw too much current.
I have considered using an oscillator circuit with a transformer and voltage multiplier setup. I was thinking about using a ZVS driver or a 555 timer but I don't have much experience with other circuits. I don't prefer an AC or DC output.

How much current do you require?

This is kind of a specialized field of power conversion.  If you have to ask these kinds of questions on the internet, you might want to re-think trying to do it yourself.  You don't get any mistakes or do-overs with those kinds of voltages.

I’m only looking for plasma generation so I need very low current. Is there a way to current limit the battery to prevent safety issues?

Re, "...current limit the battery..." That won't necessarily keep you safe. If any part of your system has any capacitance at all, then with tens of kilovolts, it will store significant charge. CRT display tubes are notorious for this because their anodes are huge, and they are extremely well insulated. A big CRT can still deliver a dangerous—potentially lethal—shock even several weeks after the power supply has been disconnected.

CRT supplies (15-30kV) used a flyback supply, often with a voltage multiplier in one module.
X-ray tubes are usually more like 50-150kV (and substantial watts) and I believe modern supplies use a resonant push-pull transformer circuit feeding a relatively high ratio voltage multiplier.
The '40W' CO2 laser supply I'm working with at the moment appears to supply about 400W at 20kV or more. Extremely dangerous, and it's at the low end of the power scale for CO2 lasers. I think I paid $30 for it locally, they're available from the usual sources. It also doesn't at all like to be open circuit.

Thanks for the information, but I am only building a high voltage supply for plasma generation so I will not need anything as powerful as what you’re doing.

Plasma etching like for wafer fab or making plasma ball toys?

More like plasma etching but with less power
